# Picard's theorem and Cauchy sequences in different norms

Tags: uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences, equivalent-metrics, picard-scheme

I understand that in order to prove the existence and uniqueness of a solution to a first order non-linear ODE, we first convert it into an integral equation:

$y_{n+1} := Ty_{n} = y_{0} + \int_{0}^{t}f(s, y_{n})ds,$

and then show that the resulting operator is a contraction, provided that the right-hand side function is Lipschitz:

$|Ty_{n+1} - Ty_{n}| \le L \tau |y_{n+1} - y_{n}|$,

where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant and $t \in [0,\tau]$. The operator is a contraction if $L \tau<1$.

If $L \tau>1$, we define the norm $|| y ||_{\lambda} :=\sup_{0 \le t \le \tau} e^{-\lambda t}||y||$ with $\lambda>L$, which can be shown to be equivalent to $| \cdot |$. Then

$||Ty_{n+1} - Ty_{n}||_{\lambda} \leq \sup_{0 \le t \le \tau} e^{-\lambda t} ||y_{n+1}-y_{n}||_{\lambda} \frac{L}{\lambda}(e^{\lambda t}-1)
\leq \frac{L}{\lambda}||y_{n+1}-y_{n}||_{\lambda} < ||y_{n+1}-y_{n}||_{\lambda},$

i.e. the Lipschitz condition is enough for $T$ to be a contraction; we no longer need that $L \tau <1$.

If we look at the distance between Picard iterates in the $|\cdot|$ norm, we have

$|y_{n+1}-y_{n}|=|Ty_{n}-Ty_{n-1}| \leq (L\tau)^{n}|y_{n-1}-y_{n-2}| $

and

$|y_{j}-y_{i}| \leq \sum_{k=i}^{j-1}|y_{k+1}-y_{k}| \leq  \sum_{k=i}^{j-1} (L \tau)^{k} |y_{k+1}-y_{k}| $.

The sequence $y_{n}$ is Cauchy w.r.t the norm $|\cdot |$ iff $L \tau < 1$, because otherwise the geometric series above diverges.

Then how is it possible that even if $L \tau > 1$, we can still show the existence and uniqueness of solution, which is given by the limit of Picard's iterates as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Doesn't the fact that $y_{n}$ is not Cauchy in $| \cdot|$ for $L \tau >1 $ imply that it is also not Cauchy in $|| \cdot ||$, since the norms are equivalent?

I am missing something here, and I would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me where in my reasoning I'm going wrong.

Comment: There is a conflict of notation: $T$ is both an operator and the upper bound of an interval.

Comment: I don't understand what "where $L$ is the Lipschitz" means, and whether $LT$ denotes $L$ times $T$ (the Lipschitz constant times the bound of the interval) or $L$ of $T$ (the Lipschitz constant of the operator $T$).

Comment: I think that $(y_n)$ is Cauchy for both (equivalent) norms but that the norm $\|~\|_\lambda$ is just a tool to prove it easily.

Comment: But doesn't the fact that the geometric series, which gives the sum of the distance between successive terms, diverges for $ L \tau > 1$ mean that the sequence is not Cauchy in the $| \cdot |$ norm? If we pass to the limit $ j \rightarrow \infty $ in the sum, then the sum also goes to $\infty$. This is what I'm confused about.

Comment: This diverging series is only an upper bound so it does not prove the sequence is not Cauchy.